# In F#, how to construct a record list with DateTime values?

Tags: list, f#, record

In F#, assume I have a person record as:

```
type person = 
   { LastName: string option
     BirthDate: System.DateTime option }
```

Now, I want to create a list of 100 persons (this fails. Both name and The System.DateTime(...) is incorrect):

```
let people = [for a in 1 .. 100 
                do yield {
                            LastName= Some "LastName"+a 
                            BirthDate = System.DateTime(2012,11,27)
                          }]
```

How is this done?

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two separate issues with the code, but your general approach is good!

First, `Some "LastName"+a` is interpereted as `(Some "LastName")+a`, which is not the right parenthesization. Also `a` is an `int` which cannot be automatically turned into a `string`, so you need to explicitly convert it. The correct version is `Some("LastName" + string a)`.

Second, `System.DateTime(2012,11,27)` is `DateTime`, but you need an option. You can fix this just by adding `Some` and the right parentheses, i.e. `Some(System.DateTime(2012,11,27))`.

As a bonus, you can reduce `do yield` to  `->` (this is just a syntactic sugar to make this kind of thing shorter). I would write:

```
open System

let people = 
  [ for a in 1 .. 100 ->
      { LastName= Some ("LastName"+string a) 
        BirthDate = Some(DateTime(2012,11,27)) } ]
```

Comment: Would you concatenate rather than sprintf, Tomas?

Comment: I do not have a strong preference either way - I think when it's just appending a number to the end, I would use `+`. If there is more formatting going on, then `sprintf` would make that nicer.